S3 Cross Region Replication - Filter in EventBridge?
Context: I have S3 buckets setup in us-east-1 & us-west-1 regions -> both buckets fire Event Notifications on receipt of an PutObject event and these events are captured by an EventBridge rule in their respective regions. While Individual PutObject calls DIRECTLY to the s3 buckets I want to capture in Event Bridge, I've noticed the CROSS REGION REPLICATION PutObject calls that happen automatically - are also getting captured in EventBridge
Ask: i want to let each regions EventBridge pattern MATCHING to ONLY honor the DIRECT PutObject calls from in their respective region's buckets - and not the ones generated from CRR. How can I create an event pattern that allows this in each region?
Addendum: I know there's a way to do this using CloudTrail events, but I cannot use CloudTrail events in my org Thus I cannot use the following MATCH event pattern in EventBridge. I need to use S3 notification event pattern only:- (Also I cannot use s3->lambda)
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventName": ["PutObject"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "x-amz-replication-status": [{
        "exists": false
      }]
    }
  }
}

